# Iteration samples in Quick books using web connector

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I have seen documention on iterration on QBSDK_ProGuid.pdf file(page 117).i am confusion how to issue the same query again and setting iterator value now set to Continue, and the IteratorID field set to the IteratorID value returned from the first query iteration.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?qbxml version="5.0" ?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
<CustomerQueryRq requestID="5001" iterator="Continue"
iteratorID="{D7355385-A17B-4f5d-B34D-F34C79C3E6FC}">
<MaxReturned>10</MaxReturned>
<IncludeRetElement>ListID</IncludeRetElement>
</
CustomerQueryRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

I am following WCWebService sample which is provided by intuit... and getting customer data ..
can any one please provide a sample which is using iteration Concept.
Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

Below is an example of using iterators to query for a customers, fetching five (5) customers at a time. This query fetches customers with the following criteria:

- Modified after January 29th, 1984
- OwnerID is 0 (this just makes sure we get back DataExt values (custom fields) defined in the GUI)

Your initial request will look as below. Notice that we declare the iterator=“Start” attribute to start our iterator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="5.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
        <CustomerQueryRq requestID="1" iterator="Start">
            <MaxReturned>5</MaxReturned>
            <FromModifiedDate>1984-01-29T22:03:19</FromModifiedDate>
            <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
        </CustomerQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

QuickBooks will send you back a response containing the first five (5) customers that looks like below. Notice that QuickBooks has sent us back an `iteratorID="..."` attribute and an `iteratorRemainingCount="..."` attribute, indicating the ID used to identify the iterator, and the number of items left in the iterator.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRs>
        <CustomerQueryRs 
         requestID="1" 
         statusCode="0" 
         statusSeverity="Info" 
         statusMessage="Status OK" 
         iteratorRemainingCount="18"
         iteratorID="{eb05f701-e727-472f-8ade-6753c4f67a46}">
            <CustomerRet>
                <ListID>110000-1232697602</ListID>
                <TimeCreated>2009-01-23T03:00:02-05:00</TimeCreated>
                <TimeModified>2009-01-23T03:00:02-05:00</TimeModified>
                <EditSequence>1232697602</EditSequence>
                <Name>10th Customer</Name>
                <FullName>10th Customer</FullName>
                <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                <Sublevel>0</Sublevel>
                <Balance>0.00</Balance>
                <TotalBalance>0.00</TotalBalance>
                <SalesTaxCodeRef>
                    <ListID>10000-1232327562</ListID>
                    <FullName>Tax</FullName>
                </SalesTaxCodeRef>
                <ItemSalesTaxRef>
                    <ListID>10000-1232327661</ListID>
                    <FullName>Out of State</FullName>
                </ItemSalesTaxRef>
                <JobStatus>None</JobStatus>
            </CustomerRet>

             ... 4 more customer records will go here ...

        </CustomerQueryRs>
    </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

You'll then check the `iteratorRemainingCount` attribute and, if it's greater than 0, send your next request using the `iteratorID` attribute. Remember, every subsequent request request using this iterator must use the same search criteria and that search criteria must be sent with every request.

So, in this case, every request for the next part of the iterator will resend the `<MaxReturned>`, `<FromModifiedDate>`, and `<OwnerID>` elements. Notice that we send the returned `iteratorID="..."` attribute from the previous response, and declare the `iterator="Continue"` attribute indicating we want to continue fetching from an existing iterator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="5.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
        <CustomerQueryRq
         requestID="2" 
         iterator="Continue" 
         iteratorID="{eb05f701-e727-472f-8ade-6753c4f67a46}">
            <MaxReturned>5</MaxReturned>
            <FromModifiedDate>1984-01-29T22:03:19</FromModifiedDate>
            <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
        </CustomerQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

This process will repeat until there are no more items left in the iterator. On each response, you'll check the `iteratorRemainingCount` attribute, and if it's greater than 0, you'll issue another request to get the next part of the iterator.

Eventually, you'll notice that the `iteratorRemainingCount` attribute will dwindle to zero (0) at which point you'll stop issuing requests, because the iterator has no more records to return. If you do issue another request, you'll get back an error as the iterator has, at this point, expired.

```
<?xml version=“1.0” ?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRs>
    <CustomerQueryRs 
     requestID="5"  
     statusCode="0"
     statusSeverity="Info" 
     statusMessage="Status OK" 
     iteratorRemainingCount="0"
     iteratorID="{eb05f701-e727-472f-8ade-6753c4f67a46}">
        <CustomerRet>
            <ListID>1B0000-1232697643</ListID>
            <TimeCreated>2009-01-23T03:00:43-05:00</TimeCreated>
            <TimeModified>2009-01-23T03:00:43-05:00</TimeModified>
            <EditSequence>1232697643</EditSequence>
            <Name>Pat Daniels</Name>
            <FullName>Pat Daniels</FullName>
            <IsActive>true</IsActive>
            <Sublevel>0</Sublevel>
            <Balance>0.00</Balance>
            <TotalBalance>0.00</TotalBalance>
            <SalesTaxCodeRef>
                <ListID>10000-1232327562</ListID>
                <FullName>Tax</FullName>
            </SalesTaxCodeRef>
            <ItemSalesTaxRef>
                <ListID>10000-1232327661</ListID>
                <FullName>Out of State</FullName>
            </ItemSalesTaxRef>
            <JobStatus>None</JobStatus>
        </CustomerRet>

        ... 4 more customer records will go here ...

    </CustomerQueryRs>
</QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```